# Jenkins to detect Pull Request from a forked branch in Bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, devops

I have a bitbucket server that has a webhook configured with Jenkins.

Bitbucket has a master branch in it. I made changes in the local branch (let's call local_branch). When I git push --set-upstream origin local_branch this will create a forked branch in the bitbucket server.

My Jenkins cannot access the forked branch local_branch (which contains my changes) even though I added Jenkins as a user and give it read permission to my master branch. Unless I gave Jenkins read access to my forked branch, then my Jenkins can access the forked branch.

This is not intelligent if each one creates a forked branch and has to manually add Jenkins into the forked branch he/she created on the bitbucket server.

My goal is to let Jenkins trigger the job towards each person's forked branch whenever one creates a pull request from his/her forked branch on top of master branch.

Just wondering if anyone has ever encountered this.

Comment: The term "forked branch" doesn't really make any sense; just call it a "branch name" in the Bitbucket repository. In any case this is a Bitbucket issue: Git has no concept of "permissions" regarding any branch names, and GitHub doesn't provide read-protected branch names, so neither [tag:git] nor [tag:github] tags are appropriate. I don't use Bitbucket so I'm not sure about the exact mechanisms they provide, but generally you just want to give the Bitbucket "user" that reads the Bitbucket repository read-permissions for *all* branches, including newly-created ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when you said " give the Bitbucket "user" that reads the Bitbucket repository read-permissions for all branches, including newly-created ones",  can this be done the first time when we create the master branch so it will apply for all future created branches or we will need to manually add the "user" whenever there is a new created branch

Comment: Not really sure - the usual way to do this on GitHub is to create a GitHub "user" that is actually just a build account. The builder's account then gets access to everything, since the builder *is* the company, in a sense, so the company gets access to the company's repositories. (Then Jenkins or Travis-CI or CircleCI or whatever does the CI/CD building uses that "user".)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it. I have found out the problem. Yeah, the solution is to manually add the user to the permission list.